# What is the maximum likelihood estimator for $e^{-\theta}( (P(X_i = 0))$?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Suppose $X_i$ is $iid$ $Poisson(\theta)$

What is the maximum likelihood estimator for $e^{-\theta}(= P(Xi = 0))$?

I already found the MLE for the $\theta$. how do you then find the MLE of $e^{-\theta}(= P(Xi = 0))$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By the [functional invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance) property of the maximum likelihood estimator, the maximum likelihood estimator of $e^{-\theta}$ is just $\color{blue}{e^{-\widehat{\theta}_{MLE}}}$, where $\widehat{\theta}_{MLE}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

Comment: so then would that be, the MLE is: $e^{-\hat \theta} = e^{-1/n \sum X_i}$?
Since I calculate MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat \theta = 1/n \sum X_i$

Comment: Yes, that would be it.